# Can I use the JWT Token sent on my header inside my code?

Tags: c#, jwt

So I was looking around, and I was wondering if I can somehow use the jwt token I send on the header of my request for authorization inside my code somehow, or it just gets lost once the request get to the web api endpoint?

I want to use the token to extract certain information without sending the token as part of my body.

I tried using the jwt library inside my web api project but to not avail

I want to use the token to extract certain information without sending the token as part of my body. For example my email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to read the claims from the principle attached to the HttpContext

```
var identity = HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
if (identity != null)
{
    return identity.FindFirst("email").Value;   
}
```

Otherwise, you can use the JwtSecurityTokenHandler to validate the token, to obtain a principle, and then read the claim from that principle instead:

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var principle = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, .... );
return principal.Claims.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Type == "email").Value;
```

You can get the bearer token from the header from the HttpRequestMessage (request).

```
IEnumerable<string> headers;
request.Headers.TryGetValues("Authorization", out headers);
return headers.ElementAt(0); // Bearer Token
```